# WiFi not getting ON and Off

Tags: wi-fi, samsung

I have a Samsung S Duos GT-S7562. Its warranty is over. I am seeing that its **WiFi is not working now**. Whenever I try to switch it ON, it toggles between ON and OFF. I have tried a factory reset and that doesn't helped me. Request your suggestions.
My current version is Android 4.0.4

Comment: Well, usually Wi-Fi problems can be solved by performing a factory reset! But here as you have already tried doing that means now there's nothing left other than either heading over to the nearest support to solve your problem or you can try your luck by flashing the stock ROM again over to your device. PS: I am not if flashing the ROM thing is going to work or not consider it as a second opinion my first opinion will always be heading over to the nearest support to fix this one up ! See if that helps...

Comment: It could be hardware problem

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment because I do not have 50 reputation hence I am updating this as an answer.

Me too had this problem and I tried all possible troubleshooting steps with the help of almost every forum I knew to no avail. This is what I tried:

1. Installed 4-5 wifi fixer apps from play store - Did not help.
2. If you have a cwm or twrp recovery installed, try doing factory reset from recovery - I tried it on my mmx canvas hd a116 with 4.1.2 JB but did not work
3. I installed a custom rom. The device was working fine but no improvement in WiFi
4. Went to mmx service station, they asked INR 60 for checking problem and said it was a motherboard fault and would cost more than INR 4500

Finally I went to a local cell phone repair guy and got the WiFi & bluetooth IC replaced for INR 400. Now everything is working fine.